# Could not load Llama model from path: nous-hermes-13b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I get this error

```
llm = LlamaCpp(
```

File "/Users/mohamahdhour/Desktop/Coding/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/load/serializable.py", line 97, in **init**
super().**init**(**kwargs)
File "/Users/mohamahdhour/Desktop/Coding/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 341, in **init**
raise validation_error
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for LlamaCpp
**root**
Could not load Llama model from path: nous-hermes-13b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin. Received error  (type=value_error)

here is my code:

```
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import (
    StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler,
)  # for streaming resposne
from langchain.llms import OpenAI


# Make sure the model path is correct for your system!
model_path = "nous-hermes-13b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin" # <-------- enter your model path here 


template = """Question: {question}

Answer: """

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question"])

# Callbacks support token-wise streaming
callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])


n_gpu_layers = 40  # Change this value based on your model and your GPU VRAM pool.
n_batch = 512  # Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of VRAM in your GPU.



# Uncomment the code below if you want to run inference on CPU
llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path=model_path, callback_manager=callback_manager, verbose=True
)

llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)

question = "Tell me a random joke "


print(llm_chain.run(question))
```

I am using mac M1

I tried to load the model but it failed